# How to Compute Space Complexity for Printing All paths which Sum to a Given Value in Binary Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, space-complexity

This problem is from the book *Cracking the Coding Interview*, and I have trouble understanding the space complexity specified for their solution.

**Problem:**
You are given a binary tree in which each node contains a value. Design an algorithm to print all paths which sum to a given value. Note that a path can start or end anywhere in the tree.

**Solution (in Java):**

```
public static void findSum(TreeNode node, int sum, int[] path, int level) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }

    /* Insert current node into path */
    path[level] = node.data; 

    int t = 0;
    for (int i = level; i >= 0; i--){
        t += path[i];
        if (t == sum) {
            print(path, i, level);
        }
    }

    findSum(node.left, sum, path, level + 1);
    findSum(node.right, sum, path, level + 1);

    /* Remove current node from path. Not strictly necessary, since we would
     * ignore this value, but it's good practice.
     */
    path[level] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
}

public static int depth(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + Math.max(depth(node.left), depth(node.right));
    }
}

public static void findSum(TreeNode node, int sum) {
    int depth = depth(node);
    int[] path = new int[depth];
    findSum(node, sum, path, 0);
}

private static void print(int[] path, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        System.out.print(path[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**My Question:**
According to the solution, the space complexity of this solution is `O(n*log(n))`. However, I feel like the space complexity should be `O(log(n))` which represents the depth of recursion stack for the `findSum()` function. Why is my analysis wrong? Why is the space complexity `O(n*log(n))`?

Comment: You mention both space and time complexity; which are you interested in?

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. I'm talking about space complexity. I fixed the typo in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to miss ``/\``-like paths... is this the full solution?

Comment: Yes, this is the full solution. I agree that this misses /\ like paths....

Comment: Is it possible they're considering the *output text* as part of the space complexity? Or, considering that you say this book ignores important aspects of the problem in both this and the other one you asked a question about (if the trees are balanced, if the paths can go up as well as down), maybe this isn't the best book to study space complexity from? Does the book not contain explanations?

Answer (score 1):

The tree is not necessarily full - so it could have O(n) depth.
As far as I can tell, the space complexity is O(n).

Comment: Since the solution has O(n*log(n)) space complexity, I assume the problem assumes that the tree is balanced. In that case, can you explain why the space complexity is O(n*log(n))? I don't get it....

Comment: @jjwest note that O(n log n) is *worse* than O(n).

Comment: @jjwest, where does it say you can assume it's balanced? you always assume worse case if unspecified

Answer (score 0):

You're right; when the trees are balanced, this algorithm has space complexity of *O(log n)*. (Note that the solution you posted is for a different problem than the one you wrote—it's for finding **only paths that go down** the tree.) Maybe the answer in the book was misprinted. If the book truly doesn't mention whether they're dealing with balanced or unbalanced trees, or where the paths can go, misprinted this answer, and contains no explanations for how they derived their answers... come on, you should be able to find a much better book than this to study algorithm complexity from.

## Analysis

We can set aside from now if the trees are balanced by saying the depth of the tree is *d*, which is *O(log n)* if balanced, or *O(n)* if not.

There are 2 things in this algorithm that use space: the stack space used, and the array that is allocated. That `int[]` object has a size of `depth(node)`, and is allocated exactly once, in the single call to `findSum(TreeNode, int)`, so its space usage is *O(d)*.

When `findSum(TreeNode, int)` calls `depth(node)`, the stack frames will look like this:

```
[findSum(TreeNode, int)] [depth] ... [depth]
```

The furthest `depth()` can recurse is the depth of the tree, so the stack usage here is *O(d)*.

Next, `depth()` finishes, and we call the recursive `findSum(TreeNode, int, int[], int)`.

This function doesn't allocate any new memory, and it recurses to the depth of the tree just like `depth()`, so the stack usage here is also *O(d)*.

So the maximum stack usage at any time in this algorithm is *O(d)*, which plus the *O(d)* space used by the allocated array, gives us a final answer of *O(d)*, which is *O(n)* in the general case, or *O(log n)* if the tree is balanced.

Comment: is findSum(TreeNode node, int sum) even called?

Comment: @BrandonLing That's the function that's intended to be called by the user, which calls the others as helper functions, so I'm assuming yes :) No clue why one of those helper functions is `public`.